# Proper way to call `setTimeout()`

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project at the moment and need to call the `setTimeout()` function. I can't use libraries so must be "pure" JavaScript and work in all browsers IE6+ or IE7+ at a push.

I can successfully call `setTimeout()` like this:

```
setTimeout("setOpacity('" + elementId + "'," + opacity + ")", 1000);
```

and it works as expected, but its string evaluation and I can just image in the future doing one with far more variables and it not working so want to get the technique down now.

I did try the following:

```
setTimeout(function () { setOpacity(elementId, opacity); }, 1000);
```

but instead of it doing the timeout, it executed straight away.

Is it possible to call `setTimeout()` here without using string evaluation?

Comment: Why do you think _"it executed straight away"_ give it `10000` instead of `1000` and find out.

Comment: Your second version is correct. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
function delayedCall(callback, timeout, params) {
    setTimeout(function() { callback.apply(null, params); }, timeout);
}

delayedCall(setOpacity, 1000, [elementId, opacity]);
```

Comment: It's just like call `setTimeout` but less efficient and way less readable!

Comment: THIS WORKS! But why?! I tested on Chrome, Firefox and IE7 and they all worked (don't have IE6 to test at the moment)

Comment: I think You not properly used external variables (elementId and opacity), and in my variant its var's copied all times into "params". But I could be wrong.

Comment: Not sure I understand that. This also works: `function delayedCall(callback, timeout, elementId, opacity) {
    setTimeout(function() { setOpacity(elementId, opacity); }, timeout);
}`

Comment: I think I understand what you were saying now. In my version, the variables were being passed by reference NOT by value, which caused problems because I was changing the value for the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think *"it executed straight away"*?
One second isn't enough time of humans...

Give it `10000` instead of `1000` and see that it does work as expected.

```
setTimeout(function () { setOpacity(elementId, opacity); }, 10000); // 10 secs
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WFJC8/)

Comment: I'd be in serious doubt about myself not realizing a one second difference.

Comment: The code was part of an animation that worked for the string eval method, but just skipped the whole animation and set its opacity to 0 for function version.....I will try that function on its own.

Answer (score 0):

The second way should work.

Maybe the reason in your case is other, maybe when you did the first way the variables you passed were in the right scope but not when call from inside another function.